# Is any standard way to role based access file in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, roles

I have developed 4 roles access projects in angular. The dashboard have different content pages. Whenever logged in the portal intially called dashboard page.

This dashboard content will shows based on logged **user role**. I have used **ngSwitch**. Anyone knows a different way implementation instead of using **ngSwitch**. Kindly share your answer. **It's working but I want different solution**

I have explained what i did,

defined 4 role

> SuperAdmin, Admin, AdminUser, User

I have created 4 component files. follow this code component.ts file

```
  export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
   userRole: string;
   constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
   this.userRole = this.authService.userRole();
  }
```

html file:

```
  <div [ngSwitch]="userRole">
    <app-header-component title="Dashboard" *ngSwitchCase="'SuperAdmin'">
    </app-header-component>

    <app-system-integrator-dashboard *ngSwitchCase="'Admin'">                
    </app-system-integrator-dashboard>

    <app-organization-admin-dashboard *ngSwitchCase="'AdminUser'">              
    </app-organization-admin-dashboard>

    <app-organization-user-dashboard *ngSwitchCase="'User'">                
    </app-organization-user-dashboard> 
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not an answer to the question, but rather a tip. Remember that anything executed on (or sent to) the client should be considered public. Thus, hiding content with angular doesn't mean that the user cannot access it.

Answer (score 2):

create directive like

```
/* Usage : *roleIsOneOf="[userType.ADMIN, userType.ANALYST, userType.SUPER_ANALYST]" */
@Directive({
    selector: '[roleIsOneOf]',
})
export class RoleIsOneOfDirective {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    @Input() set roleIsOneOf(allowedRoles: Role[]) {
        const userRole: Role = this.authService.userRole();
        if (allowedRoles.includes(userRole)) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a structural directive like this is similar to our approach.

Comment: Concise yet effective solution for role based access control.